# Demonstrative pronouns or definitive articles?

Tags: pronoun, article, grammar-identification, determiners

Reading »Der Corona Schock« Hans-Werner Sinn, page 57:

> Vom Gipfel von Madrid im Jahr 1995, als die Zeitschiene für die Einführung des Euro verbindlich beschlossen wurde, bis hin zur Lehman-Krise im Jahr 2008 sind die Preise **der** in Italien produzierten Güter relativ zu den Preisen **der** in Deutschland produzierten Güter insgesamt um etwa 40 Prozent gestiegen.
> <sub>*[Source](https://books.google.at/books?id=DeLkDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT40&lpg=PT40)*</sub>

Are these two uses of »der« demonstrative pronouns ? Or are they genitive definite articles ?

Comment: They are genitive definite articles.

Comment: More specifically, *in X produzierten Güter* is a single noun phrase, with *Güter* the noun ("goods") and *in X produzierten* acting as an adjective ("produced in X"). German allows such adjective phrases to be placed in front of the noun while English has them follow the noun: "goods produced in X" rather than "produced in X goods". If you remove the *in X produzierten* parts then the answer is clear.

Comment: @RDBury: Please to not use comments to answer questions! Please write proper answers!

Comment: @infinitezero: Same for you!

Comment: @Hubert Schölnast: Well, technically my comment was expanding on another comment and, while it gives a hint, doesn't actually answer the question. But I take your point. In any case, my answer would not have included anything not covered in your answer.

Comment: See: https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1658/1487

Comment: @Hubert Schölnast I don't consider my comment to be an answer. I believe an is it X or Y question deserves a more elaborate answer than it's X/Y. In that way, I like to deliver this as a comment, "yes, your initial idea is right" but I'm not even sure it suffices the minimum amount of characters need to post an answer

Comment: @infinitezero: The OP asks *»Are these two uses of »der« demonstrative pronouns? Or are they genitive definite articles?«* And you wrote: *»They are genitive definite articles.«* What else is this but an answer? Quote from https://german.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment: **When shouldn't I comment? -> Answering a question** ... instead, post an actual answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both cases this an article:

- plural
- genitive
- definite

And in both cases this article is the determiner of the noun *»Güter«* (goods, commodities, merchandise) which is genitive plural form of the neuter noun *»das Gut«.*

The nominal phrases, in which they live, are:

- Subject of the sentence, in nominative case, plural:

  > die Preise der in Italien produzierten Güter
- Dative object, also plural (dative case is not ruled by a verb but by the preposition *»zu«*):

  > den Preisen der in Deutschland produzierten Güter

Both parts of speech begin with the same core (but in different cases) which is *»die Preise«, »den Preisen«* (both of them consisting of a definite article, as determiner and a noun). Right of both cores are two very similar genitive attributes:

> der in Italien produzierten Güter
> der in Deutschland produzierten Güter

Both of them have their own core noun at the end which is the noun *»Güter«* and a determiner (here a definite article) at the beginning. Between the determiner and the noun is an attribute that again has its own attribute.

The core of this attribute is the word *»produzierten«* which is a participle (participle II of the verb *»produzieren«* = to produce) that behaves like an adjective (participles are verb-adjective-hybrids).

And in both cases this word *»produzierten«* (which, as just said, is by itself an attribute of a noun) has its own attribute which is an adverbial term (*»adverbiale Bestimmung«*) that consists of a preposition (*»in«*) and the name of a location (here the name of a country). Such local adverbial term satisfy the function of a locative case in other languages, so you might call it also a *"locative term".*

- *»in Italien«* is an adverbial term and this adverbial term is the attribute of *»produzierten«.*
- *»in Italien produzierten«* is the composite attribute of the noun *»Güter«.* The core of this composite attribute is a participle II which is by itself is attributed by an adverbial term.
- *»der in Italien produzierten Güter«* is a nominal group in genitive case plural. It consists of a determiner (the article *»der«*) and the noun *»Güter«* which is the core of the nominal group. This core noun has on its left side an attribute (*»in Italien produzierten«*) which is a composite attribute
- *»die Preise der in Italien produzierten Güter«* is a nominal group in nominative case. It consists of a determiner (the article *»die«*), the noun *»Preise«*, which is the core of the nominal group, and on its right side a genitive attribute (*»der in Italien produzierten Güter«*).
- *»den Preisen der in Deutschland produzierten Güter«* is very similar to the item above, it just is in dative case, and contains another noun (*»Deutschland«*) inside the adverbial term.